# Weird C library linkage issues on Mac - Segmentation Fault

Tags: macos, c, segmentation-fault

I have a strange segmentation fault that doesn't exist when everything is in 1 .c file, but does exist when I put part of the code in a *dynamically linked library* and link it to a test file. The complete code for the working 1 .c file code is at the bottom, the complete code for the error system with 2 .c and 1 .h file come first.

Here is the error system:

**example.h**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct MYARRAY {
  int len;
  void* items[];
} MYARRAY;

MYARRAY *collection;

void
mypush(void* p);
```

**example.c**:

```
#include "example.h"

void
mypush(void* p) {
  printf("Here %lu\n", sizeof collection);
  puts("FOO");
  int len = collection->len++;
  puts("BAR");
  collection->items[len] = p;
}
```

**example2.c**:

This is essentially a test file:

```
#include "example.h"

void
test_print() {
  puts("Here1");
  mypush("foo");
  puts("Here2");
}

int
main() {
  collection = malloc(sizeof *collection + (sizeof collection->items[0] * 1000));
  collection->len = 0;
  puts("Start");
  test_print();
  puts("Done");
  return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**:

I link `example` to `example2` here, and run:

```
example:
  @clang -I . -dynamiclib \
    -undefined dynamic_lookup \
    -o example.dylib example.c
  @clang example2.c example.dylib -o example2.o
  @./example2.o
.PHONY: example
```

The output is:

```
$ make example
Start
Here1
Here 8
FOO
make: *** [example] Segmentation fault: 11
```

But it should show the full output of:

```
$ make example
Start
Here1
Here 8
FOO
BAR
Here2
Done
```

The weird thing is everything works if it is this system:

**example.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct MYARRAY {
  int len;
  void* items[];
} MYARRAY;

MYARRAY *collection;

void
mypush(void* p) {
  printf("Here %lu\n", sizeof collection);
  puts("FOO");
  int len = collection->len++;
  puts("BAR");
  collection->items[len] = p;
}

void
test_print() {
  puts("Here1");
  mypush("foo");

  puts("Here");
}

int
main() {
  collection = malloc(sizeof *collection + (sizeof collection->items[0] * 1000));
  collection->len = 0;
  puts("ASF");

  test_print();

  return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**:

```
example:
  @clang -o example example.c
  @./example
.PHONY: example
```

Wondering why it's creating a segmentation fault when it is linked like this, and what I am doing wrong.

I have checked `otool` and with `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=YES` and it shows it is importing the dynamically linked libraries, but for some reason it's segmentation faulting when linked but works fine when it isn't linked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is this, in `example.h`:

```
MYARRAY *collection;
```

Since both `main.c` and `example.c` include this file, you end up defining `collection` twice, which results in undefined behavior. You need to make sure you define each object only once. The details are relatively unimportant since anything can happen with undefined behavior, but what's probably happening is that `main.c` is allocating memory for one object, but the one `example.c` is using is still `NULL`. As mentioned in the comments, since you define `collection` in `main.c` your linker is able to build the executable without needing to look for that symbol in the dynamic library, so you don't get a link time warning about it being defined there too, and obviously there'd be no cause for a warning at the time you compile the library.

It works for you when you put everything in one file because obviously then you're not defining anything twice, anymore. The error itself is nothing to do with the fact you're using a dynamic library, although that may have made it harder to detect.

It would be better to define this in `example.c` and provide a constructor function, there's no need for `main()` to be able to access it directly. But if you must do this, then define it in `example.c` and just declare an `extern` identifier in the header file to tell `main.c` that the object is defined somewhere else.

Comment: To further your explanation, there is no link time warnnig because `collection` is defined both in the executable and in a dynamically linked library... definitely 2 separate objects

Comment: @chqrlie: Good addition, added to answer.

Comment: I did a try on MacOS X, I had the same segmentation fault. Having only the declaration of _collection_ in the header file and declaring it in _exemple.c_  the execution is ok. Up vote of course ^^